# A phenomenon where job titles are indiscriminately given

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, terminology

We working in a company where we have a situation wherein numbers of some of the department's pretty inept and incompetent managements are unscrupulously awarding their subordinates (mostly out of nepotism, cronyism or flat out ethnic favoritism) therefore a similar officer in our front line department gets a title say after 2-3 years but these departments who are suppose rather support departments like Learning and development, procurement, cost control departments get doled out high classed job titles such as team leader engineer, snr team leader engineer, lead team leader engineer or lead team leader engineer which in itself are irrational. However we stay as engineer and snr. engineers for long.

Of course with job title their benefit band perks also increase.

Bottom line is our top management and HR turn blind eye to this and it is departmental decision.

Question is what is nearest term for this unscrupulous phenomenon of upgrading with themselves higher titles called.

Comment: [*Aggrandisement*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aggrandisement) and [*self-aggrandisement*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-aggrandisement), perhaps?

Comment: How about *cronyism*? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cronyism: the unfair practice by a powerful person (such as a politician) of giving jobs and other favors to friends. Usually involves politicians but could be used more broadly. Perhaps *favoritism*?

Comment: "title inflation"

Comment: This is known as a *failing* company.

Comment: I believe that @RichardKayser has supplied a good answer. However you should be aware that your OP contains many grammatical errors, which it would be beneficial to you to work on through our sister site *English Language Learners*.

Answer (score 1):

How about cronyism?

From Merriam-Webster (M-W):

> [*cronyism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cronyism): the
>   unfair practice by a powerful person (such as a politician) of giving
>   jobs and other favors to friends.

*Cronyism* often involves politicians but could be used more broadly.

Also, perhaps *favoritism*? From M-W:

> [*favoritism*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favoritism):
>   the unfair practice of treating some people better than others

*Favoritism* is more general but still works.

Comment: Would like some thing more specific or even a made up term with two and two words together...like you call Empty suits to mean people with no caliber but showy presentation. (inside empty outside show).. title inflation would do the trick..I didnt see it until i wrote the other comment...

Comment: @Anup Thanks. You should make your desires clear in your question. Perhaps an edit is in order.